# Remove space between Oracle APEX page items

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created two APEX checkbox items on top of each other, one being the checkbox selections (complete, incomplete) and one being a select all option above it (with associated JavaScript to enable the select all functionality). Everything works great, but I am trying to remove the white space in between the page items.

The checkbox item with the selections has no label because the Select All item has the heading for both items to be treated as "one item" to the user. I think the template might still be accounting for the label padding, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know a solution in order to remove the white space (I'd be find with a small amount of white space but right now it is very large and doesn't look visually appealing.

[image]

Comment: Check what Label Template has been selected for the Complete/Incomplete item. You may need to try "Hidden Label". After that, I'd examine the html being generated and look at some CSS to reduce the height of whatever is being put in that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the template options, and set the desired margin attributes to 'None'

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott - thank you! What version of APEX are you in? For some reason I don't have the Advanced pane for the Template Options.

Comment: Hard to say what's in older versions of APEX... You can do this with manual CSS too, but we don't have access to your page. Try using your browser's developer tools to isolate the element with the padding (it could be a wrapper div with a class like "t-Form-fieldContainer"). In Chrome's Elements tab, you'll see a Computed tab on the right. You can use that to see the box model values.

Comment: Yeah, this was from 19.2. I saw you tagged the question as 5.1, but I couldn't quite remember what template options were available then. I do remember now these margins weren't always there...

Comment: The "Advanced" pane shown in this answer will be available if the "region type" for the region containing checkboxes is set to `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

Non-intuitive workaround:

1. Switch the APEX item's **Appearance > Template** to "**Optional**" (or "**Required**").  *That exposes the item's Layout Column Span attribute.*
2. Set **Label Column Span** to **0**.  *That suppresses item's label so that it needs no extra white space around it for a label.*

What contributes to the white space in your case:
when an Apex Item > **Appearance** > is set to "Optional **- Above**" (or "Required **- Above**") that **renders white space above the item (for the label) even for blank labels**.  Alas, that Appearance lacks an equivalent attribute to suppress the white space label.

That **helps** control the white space but perfecting it requires the additional solutions on this article to manage the item "**margin**" and "**padding**".